# How to embed framework without copying in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, cocoa-touch

If I link `Cocoa Touch Framework` into a project without copying but only linking then I get a linker error which says, framework is not at the location.

It worked in Xcode 6, but not in Xcode 7. Do you know any workaround?

I see one can set more attribute when embedding framework, but `Location` can not set to `relative`, only `absolute` available.

[image]

Comment: Does that work if you add the framework to the overall Project and not just a single Target like you appear to be doing in this screen shot?

Comment: there is no setting for frameworks under Project only under Targets

Comment: You want it embedded — which the dictionary defines as "fixed ... in a surrounding mass" but without it being within the surrounding mass?

Comment: I want embed as in Xcode 6, add as reference without copying every time when framework was built