# How to embed framework without copying in project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode8

[There was a similar question, but the answer is no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811068/how-to-embed-framework-without-copying-in-xcode-7)

I use appodeal-ios-sdk-mobile-adapter. I want to add them to your projects without copying each.
[image]
in the Link Binary with Libraries framework added
But I get:

**ld: framework not found GoogleMobileAds**

**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add the framework to your project without copying proeta folder, drag the folder using the (**Create groups**), and add the path where you have a set framework -> "**Build Setting -> Library Search Paths** and **Framework Search Paths**

> /Users/username/Framework/AppodealAdapters/**

Answer (score 0):

Well you can open the system directory where all the frameworks are present
that is in the system folder where all the frameworks are installed

**Hit Shift+Command+G**

and use the below address

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks**

Once in the directory copy the framework which you want to use. Take care to not mess around other frameworks in this directory.

Once the frameworks are copied into this directory you can add them to your project just like you include a regular system defined framework.

Try it out it works for me. I am using XCode 7.3.

Comment: Perhaps it is also a solution. But I need to be in a framework on a disk folder, the folder is updated with github. I'm use **create folder references**, but again I get the same error

Comment: Yes the framework needs to be on your disk first, once you have the framework on your disk then you can follow the above method. Download the framework from github as a zip and continue.    In the project navigator, select your project.